# Excel Highlight Cells Greater than

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, highlighting

I am doing a price comparison of various items with last year and this year.
so in column F i list current price and Column I with previous price. I want to highlight the cells which has higher price compared to last year. I did the conditional formatting with greater than rule for specific row  Cell value > $F3 format applies to =$I$3. I want to apply this format to entire column. like if >$F4 format applies to =$I$4 likewise up to 220. IS there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Used formulae =F3:F220>I3:I220 format applies to =F$3:F$220. It's working.